# File I/O issue with while loops

Tags: c++

The program must loop, read in the data, calculate the values for each employee and output the results to a text file.

The problem is that the while loop in my code is looping infinitely and I am not sure how to make it stop (at the point where next line isn't what we are looking for). The compiler is not catching what is wrong and I cannot find a viable answer elsewhere on the Internet.

```
inFile >> employee_number >> hourly_rate >> hours_worked >> dependents >> full_time;

while (employee_number == 1)
{
    count++;

    PayrollMath(hours_worked, hourly_rate, base_pay, gross_pay, overtime_hours, overtime_pay, double_overtime_hours, double_overtime_pay);

    IRA_Deduction = RetirementSavings(gross_pay);
    mod_gross_pay = gross_pay - IRA_Deduction;

    taxes_withheld = IncomeTaxWithholding(dependents, mod_gross_pay);
    net_pay = mod_gross_pay - taxes_withheld;

    MedicalDeductions(net_pay, full_time, medical_benefits);

    number_of_employed = count;

    ProgramOutput(number_of_employed, hours_worked, hourly_rate, base_pay, overtime_hours, overtime_pay, double_overtime_hours,
                  double_overtime_pay, gross_pay, IRA_Deduction, mod_gross_pay, taxes_withheld, net_pay, medical_benefits);

}

cout << " Successful Completion!" << endl;

outFile.close();
inFile.close();
```

Comment: What steps are you taking to break out of the loop?

Comment: as juanchopanza said you are not doing anything to change the condition. You must modify employee_number to not be 1 to get out of the loop as that is the condition you set. You may also call break; to exit the loop but it is not recommended.

Comment: Why is the read outside the loop? Why aren't you checking whether or not the input succeeded?

Comment: That's where my question lies, how to break out of the loop by only checking the file that's being called.

Comment: Please include a simple example of typical file content that the code is supposed to deal with. Is there more content after the sequence to be read, or are you trying to detect the end-of-file with "0"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of your code, only containing what matters for the loop's behaviour:

```
inFile >> employee_number >> hourly_rate >> hours_worked >> dependents >> full_time;

while (employee_number == 1)
{
    count++;
    number_of_employed = count;
}

outFile.close();
inFile.close();
```

In the loop, you are repeatedly checking for a condition to change to a value that would indicate the time where the loop should be broken. The problem is that your condition is constant, as the variable used in the condition is not modified during every loop iteration. The condition evaluates to the same value over and over again, never giving the loop a chance to break by changing the condition.

```
while(employee_number == 1){...} // employee_number is untouched

while(true){...} // equivalent, as condition never changes (is constant)
```

To make the loop break at some point, you need to modify the variable(s) used in the condition inside the loop.

```
while(employee_number == 1){... /* modifying emloyee_number */ ...}
```

If we assume you want to read every line until the next line reads employee_number as 0, this is what I think you should be using:

```
while (true)
{
    inFile >> employee_number >> hourly_rate >> hours_worked >> dependents >> full_time;
    if (employee_number == 0) break;

    number_of_employed++;

    // Do your things with the line readings
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I am taking it solely from a text file that has already been provided. I need it to break when the next line is a 0 instead of a 1, which is what is being checked. So I added: " inFile >> employee_number; " which broke the loop but didn't change anything in the sent out file.

Comment: Please describe in the question what the loop does and on what occasion it should break exactly. I'm suspecting you want to check for the condition at every line read, so why is the read not inside the loop? And why does it only read once? For the purpose of the given code, you can also just put an if statement (and then the infinite loop inside is what your problem is, I guess).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Okay, what I want the loop to do is to read the line after "full_time" and determine if that is a 1 or a 0, if it's a 1, I want the loop to run again and output all of the output that it did last time, whilst counting how many times it does this. I want it to loop until the line after "full_time" is a 0.

Comment: You do notice that when you read into several variables but the line only contains char "0", you'll possibly get errors because of end-of-file or start reading things after the "0" line, moving the input iterator forward.